# Reading and storing large matrix file for GPU

Tags: c++, c, matrix, gpu, sparse-matrix

Goal: Storing a large matrix in memory (Radon matrix), and transferring it into GPU memory for massively parallel operations.

Problem: Horrible reading time, and potentially sub-optimal use of space (but non-limiting for the program's usage)

I have the possibility of doing this in either C or C++.

The files which I'm receiving are parsed as follows:

0.70316,0.71267,0.72221,0.73177,0.74135,0.75094,0.76053,0.77011,0.77967,0.7892,0.79868,0.80811,0.81747

and this goes on for at least 50MB.

My naïve implementation:

```
float ** Radon;
Radon = (float **)malloc(HeightxNproj * sizeof(float *));

for (int i = 0; i < Hauteur * Nproj; i++)
    Radon[i] = (float *)malloc(WidthSquared * sizeof(float));

FILE *radonFile;

radonFile = fopen("radon.txt", "r");

if (radonFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Radon file opening failed.");
    return -1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < HeightxNproj; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < WidthSquared; j++)
    {
        fscanf(radonFile, "%f,", &Radon[i][j]);
    }
}

fclose(radonFile);
printf("Radon loaded.");
```

I'm programming for windows. I've read a bit about File Memory Mapping, but I don't know if this method, which is not actually storing the matrix in memory, is compatible with GPGPU programming. I'm using CUDA, and I'll have to pass this matrix onto GPU memory for parallel operations.

This file-reading method performs terribly, it's taking roughly a minute to read and parse the 50MB file. Is there a way to shorten reading and parsing time? The matrix is also a sparse matrix, are there common ways to deal with such matrix?

Comment: Parsing floating point values from text has horrible performance, especially with `fscanf`: it is a surprisingly complex problem if you have to be extremely precise (especially if you are given input besides the precision of your target FP type); also, `fscanf` has to deal with extra constraints (locales, locking, ...) and you are paying for the `fscanf` overhead (e.g. parsing the format string) for each single value. You should either parse straight binary data from mapping the file in memory (or straight reading it in memory if it's not too big), or use a more efficient parsing strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, at least I understand a bit more what happens behind the curtains and why it is so slow. Selected answer's method gives me a reading time that is extremely faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more separate accessing of a file the more performance you lose. The first step you should take is to estimate number of information you need to read from the file and read it in one take. It will increase your performance by huge amount. You can use memory mapped files.

> and this goes on for at least 50MB.

This is not that much.

> The files i'm receiving are parsed as follows:
>   0.70316,0.71267,0.72221,0.73177,0.74135,0.75094,0.76053,0.77011,0.77967,0.7892,0.79868,0.80811,0.81747

- Save it in binary to save about half of the memory (maybe even more). This will also increase reading speed.
- Read the whole file at one time.

An example will make you realize how naive and slow is your approach:

Once I was implementing algorithm that was reading `.obj` 3d model. The model was like 10 MB and it took around 1-2 minute to load. This was very strange, because Blender could load it immediately - maybe 1 or 2 seconds. Mapping whole file to memory and pre-allocating buffers allowed me to load the file in less than 5 secs.

Note:

> I can do this in either C or C++, both are ok.

Don't ever mix C with C++ when it comes to memory management, unless you are sure what you are doing. C++ exceptions can cause huge memory leaks if you don't protect C dynamically allocated memory using RAII.

Comment: Thansk for the response. I have no control over the incoming files, but i'll discuss that with the ones providing me the files. For the memory mapped files, will I be able to transfert the data to the GPU? without GPU memory mapped files would be the solution, but with different memory storage for cpu and gpu i don't know if this would work. (Post edit) I'll try reading the file in one go, would putting the whole file in a string / char ** and doing the parsing after that result in such gain of time? Or is it really the binarization that'd save this much?

Comment: Both: the binarization and reading whole file will give you huge boost. You don't need to change incoming files. Create cache file, that will be "binarized" once and then every access to the data saved in this file will be a lot faster. Memory mapped files shouldn't make any difference to the GPU: it is just a way to access file data.

Comment: Using this method makes a file that is double+ the size of the original file, but the reading went from a complete minute to under half a second. Many thanks!

Comment: The size could double, because I considered only that most numbers you shown are using 7 ASCII characters + one comma as separator that is 8 bytes. Converted to floats it would take in most cases 4 bytes each so half the size. Congrats for making algorithm faster :)

Comment: Thanks, it doubled because 60% of the file were 0, due to the matrix being sparse, now those 0 are stored in 4 bytes each indeed